# Realm policies and user graph

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform

This is an architecture question regarding the Realm Platform.

First, I think Realm is great. I'm a huge advocate. I'm trying to convince my team to get the enterprise addition and sync it with our postgresql backend.

Here is what I need to be able to explain:

Lets say you have a chat application all in one synced realm. It has users and chats. User A and User B have a chat. User C now get all that chat history synced to the device even though they do not care about that chat.

How do I model this is Realm? If user C got invited to that chat how would I handle that?

Comment: You should have a separate Realm for each user, where you only store the chat history between that specific user and anyone else and only sync the user-specific Realm to each user's device.